# Is it normal to have loads of connections between node and mongo when using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to figure out a performance issue and I was wondering if it is normal to have around 30 (I guess 15 per cpu on 2 cpus in cluster configuration) different connections. That number seams to be consistent but I am not sure why.

Comment: Silly question, but are you closing your connection properly?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not closing the connection at all. Just launching the express app where the connection is established only once.

For some reason I am not getting the performance I want and it feels that it is somehow related to usage of mongo, mongoose or the combination of both. I was wondering if this could be due to the high number of connections between both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, make sure you are closing your connections when the Node process restarts. Something like this:

```
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  mongoose.connection.close(function () {
    console.log('Mongoose default connection disconnected through app termination');
    process.exit(0);
  });
});
```

There's more on managing a default Mongoose connection here: http://theholmesoffice.com/mongoose-connection-best-practice/

Also note that you can specify the poolSize per connection. The default is 5.

```
var uri = 'mongodb://localhost/test';
mongoose.createConnection(uri, { server: { poolSize: 4 }});
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#connection_pools