# How to set up Mongoose and connect-mongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, connect-mongo

I had an [Error setting TTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887737/error-setting-ttl-index-on-collection-sessions-on-socket-reconnect) error when starting my application in Express. Maybe the problem is because I use for sessions and for DB operations the same database through different connections.

So it there a specific sequence of requiring `connect-mongo` and `mongoose` that needs to be respected if I want to store my sessions in MongoDB via the `connect-mongo` middleware and use Mongo as my database for my app-specific data?

Currently my app looks like this:

```
App.app.use(express.session({
store: new MongoStore({
    db: settings.cookie.db,
    host: settings.cookie.host,
    port: settings.cookie.port
}),
    secret: settings.cookie.secret
}))
```

and later I set start the connection for Mongo:

```
 function connect(connectionString) {
     mongoose.connect(connectionString)

     var db = mongoose.connection
     db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error'))
     db.once('open', function callbck() {
        console.log('Mongoose connected at: ', connectionString)
       })
     }
```

There are no error logs apart.

Also how do I tear down properly Mongo connections when I close my app (from command line let's say)? For this question I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896394/is-it-normal-to-have-loads-of-connections-between-node-and-mongo-when-using-mong) I think.

Answer (score 6):

First of all i've created a sessionStore module

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
express = require('express'),
MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express),
sessionStore = new MongoStore({mongoose_connection: mongoose.connection});
module.exports = sessionStore;
```

Then i've included it into app

```
sessionStore = require('libs/sessionStore');
```

And finaly

```
app.use(express.session({
  secret: config.get('session:secret'),
  key: config.get('session:key'),
  cookie: config.get('session:cookie'),
  store: sessionStore
}));
```

That's config

```
"session": {
    "secret": "secret",
    "key": "connect.sid",
    "cookie": {
        "path": "/",
        "httpOnly": true,
        "maxAge": null
    }
},
```